# How can I CREATE SECURE VIEW in Snowflake and set the column Type size away from default as eg. VARCHAR(256) without creating a temp table

Tags: sql, types, google-bigquery, snowflake-cloud-data-platform, snowflake-schema

I'm trying to use our CREATE SECURE VIEW script in snowflake that we use for automated data shares but we need to limit the character lengths from the maximum VARCHAR(16777216) to something more usable by external shareholder middleware.

```
CREATE SECURE VIEW EXAMPLE_TABLE AS   
SELECT COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(256)   
FROM DB.TABLE
```

Also tried

```
CREATE SECURE VIEW EXAMPLE_TABLE AS   
SELECT (CAST COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(256))  
FROM DB.TABLE
```

Comment: The cast version should work, but you also have to name the view column.

Comment: Hi - I am not sure why you are trying to control the size of a column in a view as presumably it could be truncating data without you realising it. If you have data in the underlying tables that is larger than you want expose via the share then you should explicitly handle it (e.g. using LEFT, SUBSTR, etc) rather than having mismatched column sizes between a view and its source table

Answer (score 0):

You have to specify the column name again

IE

```
CAST(COLUMN1 AS VARCHAR(256)) AS COLUMN1
```

Comment: otherwise you will get SQL compilation error: Missing column specification as an error